# how to find unknown third side length when given 2 side lengths and an opposite angle

Tags: trigonometry

$\triangle ABC$ with:

$\angle A = 65^{\circ}$

$\overline{BC}=a = 8 \text{km}$

$\overline{CA}=b = 6 \text{km}$

What is the length of side $\overline{AB}=c$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the law of cosines? This is a very straightforward application of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Find $\sin B = \dfrac{b\sin A}{a}$, and then find $B$, then find $C = 180^{\circ} - A - B$, and then use $c = \dfrac{a\sin C}{\sin A}$

Answer (score 0):

#### Hint:

Drop a perpendicular line from $C$ to $AB$, with intersection $D$, and then work out the perpendicular distance $d=\overline{CD}$ and the distance $\overline{AD}$. Then from Pythagoras' theorem on the right-angled triangle $\triangle BCD$ with hypotenuse $8$ and side $d$, find out what is $\overline{DB}$.

Result: $8\cos(65^\circ)+\sqrt{6^2-(8\sin(65^\circ))^2}\approx8.403$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The sine law says:

$$\frac{8}{6}=\frac{a}{b}= \frac{\sin A}{\sin B} =\frac{\sin 65^{\circ}}{\sin B}$$

From here, $\sin B= \frac{3}{4} \sin{65^{\circ}}$ and $B = \arcsin (\frac{3}{4} \sin{65^{\circ}}= 42.8226..^{\circ}$) (only one solution in this case for $B$, as the picture indicates) and so $C = 180^{\circ} - A - B = 180^{\circ} - 65^{\circ} - B = 72.177386...^{\circ}$ and therefore
$$c = \frac{\sin C}{\sin A} \cdot a = 8.4034...$$